# How to scroll all the way through a followers list in instagram?

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, web-scraping, scroll, instagram

So I've been working on a project recently, and I need to get a user's followers list.
To do so, I use **Selenium** in **Python**.

I first log in, and after clicking a few buttons, I click on the Followers button of the user.
Then, a "box" appears, with some of his followers.
However, the list only contains **12** followers, and to load more, you need to **scroll all the way down, wait a bit, then scroll again** etc...

So my problem is I don't know how to scroll through this box!
I looked on the website searching for some solutions to my problem, but all of them didn't work for me.
One of the possibilities is that maybe I selected the wrong element, but I tested a lot of XPath and still none worked.

So if someone could help me I would be very grateful!

So here's my code :

```
# After clicking on his followers button on his profile button

scrollable_list = driver.find_element(By.XPATH, "/html/body/div\[2\]/div/div/div\[3\]/div/div/div\[1\]/div/div\[2\]/div/div/div/div/div\[2\]/div/div/div\[3\]"
)

# Scroll 3 times

for i in range(3):
driver.execute_script("arguments\[0\].scrollTop = arguments\[0\].scrollHeight", scrollable_list)

     # Wait some time for the rest of the list to load 
     time.sleep(1.5)

# Get the usernames of the list

Followers_elements = driver.find_elements(By.XPATH, "/html/body/div\[2\]/div/div/div\[3\]/div/div/div\[1\]/div/div\[2\]/div/div/div/div/div\[2\]/div/div/div\[3\]/div\[1\]/div"
)
Followers_elements = \[element.text for element in Followers_elements\]
```

Sorry if my code is a bit messy, I'm kind of new to code, so besides my problem, if you have some bits of advice for me to write better code, let me know
And I'm sorry if you struggle to read my text, I'm not an English speaker.

Answer (score 0):

You can scroll to the bottom of the screen using:

```
driver.execute_script("window.scrollTo(0, document.body.scrollHeight);")
```

**Note**: You would be using Javascript to do so, since plain Selenium cannot do it.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but the thing is that this solution won't work for my situation. As you said, that scroll to the bottom of the screen. However, that's not what I want to do. I want to scroll down in a "window" that appears when you click the Followers button of the user, not to scroll down the page.
If you have another suggestion I would be very grateful.

Comment: See if this helps: https://www.selenium.dev/documentation/webdriver/actions_api/wheel/.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you're escaping things wrong. Try:

```
driver.execute_script("""
  arguments[0].scrollTop = arguments[0].scrollHeight
""", scrollable_list)
```

if you're not sure you're scrolling the right element, scroll it down a bit and do this in js console.

```
el = $$('*').find(el => el.scrollTop)
```